# How to Re-render a component that was already rendered after activating a props in other component

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm setting up an application in React-native where I have a:

Component A : a search component with 2 fields

Component B : a button on this page where I click on it, the 3rd field appears

This components are only linked with react-navigation

In my case, the component B is a component where I can buy premium, and I want to update the component A when premium bought.

The problem : when I already rendered the Component A, and the I go to Component B, click the button, the Component A does not re-render, how can I do it ?

I'm looking for something like this :

```js
class ComponentA extends PureComponent {

render() {
    if (userHasNotClickedOnComponentB) {
      return (
        <SearchForm/>
      )
    } else {
        return (
          <SearchFormPremium/>
        )
      }
  }
}
```

SearchForm and SearchFormPremium are two separated Component: 
One with the Premium functionalities, the other one for normal users only

I already rendered ComponentA, and then I go to ComponentB and click the button

```js
class ComponentB extends PureComponent {

render() {
    return (
       <Button onClick={() => setPremium()}/>
      )
  }
}
```

How can the ComponentA re-render so i can have the changes of ComponentB ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you navigating using this.props.navigation.navigate('routeName') to component B and then click on the button and after that came again on component A using goBack prop ? or these components are on the same screen?

Comment: Components are independent. I navigate with navigation.navigate('route name') for this case. You can't send a function update in the navigation params for example, because this route is called in many different cases in my app

Comment: Are you want to update your code while you go onto navigating back ? there is two options for you one is passing update function in params and place a check into your B component if that components gets this function then execute your update logic otherwise component B don't need to execute your update function you can also an empty function with other routes and other option is you can execute an update function while navigating back.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into using Redux, or something of the like to keep a centralized store that all of your components can look at. There are plenty of Redux tutorials out there so I wont go into details, but essentially it will allow you to:

1) Create a data store accessible from any 'connected' component

2) Dispatch actions from any component to update the store

When you connect a component, the connected data becomes props. So, for example, if you connected component A and B to the same slice of your store, when component A updates it, component B will automatically re-render because its props have changed.

[Redux github page](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, with Redux it worked !

Just connect both component. In ComponentA (the component that has to be automatically updated) use the function componentWillReceiveProps() and refresh it inside of it.

In Reducer :

```
const initialState = {premium: false};

const tooglePremiumReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "TOOGLE_PREMIUM":
      return {
        ...state,
        premium: action.payload.premium,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default tooglePremiumReducer;
```

In Action :

```
export const tooglePremiumAction = (premium) => {
    return dispatch => {
      dispatch({
        type: "TOOGLE_PREMIUM",
        payload: {
          premium: premium
        }
      });
    };
  };
```

In ComponentB :

```
// Import tooglePremiumAction
class ComponentB extends PureComponent {

render() {
    return (
       <Button onClick={() => this.props.tooglePremiumAction(true)}/>
      )
  }
}

const actions = {
  tooglePremiumAction
};

export default connect(
  actions
)(ComponentB);
```

In ComponentA:

```
class ComponentA extends PureComponent {

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(this.props.premium !== nextProps.premium) {
      //here refresh your component
    }
  }

render() {
    if (!this.props.premium) {
      return (
        <SearchForm/>
      )
    } else {
        return (
          <SearchFormPremium/>
        )
      }
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const premium = state.premium.premium
  return { premium };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ComponentA);
```